NSH gives me error when i'm building electron app
i'm trying to include font installation with myproject.exe , everything is working until i include nsh script, what could be the problem?
!macro customInstall
    # Set the font directory path
    SetOutPath "$FONTS"

    # Copy the font file to the Fonts directory
    File "${__FILEDIR__}\fonts\NotoSansGeorgian.ttf"

    # Register the font
    WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" "Noto Sans Georgian (TrueType)" "NotoSansGeorgian.ttf"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" "Noto Sans Georgian (TrueType)" "NotoSansGeorgian.ttf"

    # Send a message to all windows to notify them about the change
    System::Call 'user32::SendMessageA(i 0xffff, i ${WM_FONTCHANGE}, i 0, i 0)'
!macroend

!macro customUnInstall
    # Unregister the font
    DeleteRegValue HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" "Noto Sans Georgian (TrueType)"
    DeleteRegValue HKCU "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" "Noto Sans Georgian (TrueType)"

    # Remove the font file from the Fonts directory
    Delete "$FONTS\NotoSansGeorgian.ttf"

    # Send a message to all windows to notify them about the change
    System::Call 'user32::SendMessageA(i 0xffff, i ${WM_FONTCHANGE}, i 0, i 0)'
!macroend

I tried to test it line by line and i'm 100% sure this script has bugs

Are you getting a compiler error or does it just not work at run-time?

It's not working on run time

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I don't know anything about Electron but I do know that you should use one of the font header files from the NSIS wiki instead of coding your own. Your code never calls AddFontResource so it is not going to show up right away. If you did everything else correctly it would show up after a reboot.
You can adapt the code sample from Installing fonts to fit your needs:
!include FontInstall.nsh

!macro customInstall
!insertmacro FontInstallTTF "${__FILEDIR__}\fonts\NotoSansGeorgian.ttf" "NotoSansGeorgian.ttf" "Noto Sans Georgian"
SendMessage ${HWND_BROADCAST} ${WM_FONTCHANGE} 0 0 /TIMEOUT=5000
!macroend

!macro customUnInstall
!insertmacro FontUninstallTTF "NotoSansGeorgian.ttf" "Noto Sans Georgian"
SendMessage ${HWND_BROADCAST} ${WM_FONTCHANGE} 0 0 /TIMEOUT=5000
!macroend

(This assumes "Noto Sans Georgian" is the correct registry name. If you don't know it, use the FontInfo plug-in)
